# How to build a source file using make?

Tags: make, install-from-source, makefile

I am trying to build a source using make? This is the first time I am trying to do this as there is no other way to install the program.
Contents of directory containing the source are shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTCEq.png).

I extract the source from a casa_1.1b_.zip file.

I used a terminal.

Changed directory to this folder using `cd GA/casa_1.1b`, and ran `./configure`. And as expected it gave error `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`.
I tried unzipping the directory at `usr/local/src` and the running `./configure` but it still gave me the same error.

Do we need a configure file in source before running that command?

The contents of [MakeFile](http://ideone.com/RSJFgx) you see in the picture.

How can I go about making this source code?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.
Thanks.

**EDIT :**

```
root@pi314:/home/potato_head/GA/casa_1.1b# make
g++ -MM common/utility/PascalTriangle.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,common/utility/PascalTriangle.o common/utility/PascalTriangle.d:   ,g' > common/utility/PascalTriangle.d
g++ -MM common/utility/Combinadic.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,common/utility/Combinadic.o common/utility/Combinadic.d:   ,g' > common/utility/Combinadic.d
g++ -MM common/utility/CombinadicIterator.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,common/utility/CombinadicIterator.o common/utility/CombinadicIterator.d:   ,g' > common/utility/CombinadicIterator.d
g++ -MM minisat/solver/Solver.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,minisat/solver/Solver.o minisat/solver/Solver.d:   ,g' > minisat/solver/Solver.d
g++ -MM casa/sat/SAT.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/sat/SAT.o casa/sat/SAT.d:  ,g' > casa/sat/SAT.d
g++ -MM casa/io/Usage.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/io/Usage.o casa/io/Usage.d:   ,g' > casa/io/Usage.d
g++ -MM casa/io/SpecificationFile.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/io/SpecificationFile.o casa/io/SpecificationFile.d:   ,g' > casa/io/SpecificationFile.d
g++ -MM casa/io/ConstraintFile.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/io/ConstraintFile.o casa/io/ConstraintFile.d:    ,g' > casa/io/ConstraintFile.d
g++ -MM casa/io/OutputFile.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/io/OutputFile.o casa/io/OutputFile.d:    ,g' > casa/io/OutputFile.d
g++ -MM casa/covering/state/CoveringArray.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/covering/state/CoveringArray.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArray.d:   ,g' > casa/covering/state/CoveringArray.d
g++ -MM casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayEntry.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayEntry.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayEntry.d:    ,g' > casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayEntry.d
g++ -MM casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayRow.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayRow.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayRow.d:  ,g' > casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayRow.d
g++ -MM casa/covering/state/CoveringArraySubRow.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/covering/state/CoveringArraySubRow.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArraySubRow.d: ,g' > casa/covering/state/CoveringArraySubRow.d
g++ -MM casa/covering/space/CoveringArraySpace.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/covering/space/CoveringArraySpace.o casa/covering/space/CoveringArraySpace.d:    ,g' > casa/covering/space/CoveringArraySpace.d
g++ -MM casa/covering/space/SingleChangeSpace.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/covering/space/SingleChangeSpace.o casa/covering/space/SingleChangeSpace.d:   ,g' > casa/covering/space/SingleChangeSpace.d
g++ -MM casa/covering/space/GraftSpace.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/covering/space/GraftSpace.o casa/covering/space/GraftSpace.d:    ,g' > casa/covering/space/GraftSpace.d
g++ -MM casa/covering/bookkeeping/Options.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/covering/bookkeeping/Options.o casa/covering/bookkeeping/Options.d:   ,g' > casa/covering/bookkeeping/Options.d
g++ -MM casa/annealing/Anneal.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/annealing/Anneal.o casa/annealing/Anneal.d:   ,g' > casa/annealing/Anneal.d
g++ -MM casa/annealing/AnnealingSuccess.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/annealing/AnnealingSuccess.o casa/annealing/AnnealingSuccess.d: ,g' > casa/annealing/AnnealingSuccess.d
g++ -MM casa/annealing/Bounds.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/annealing/Bounds.o casa/annealing/Bounds.d:   ,g' > casa/annealing/Bounds.d
g++ -MM casa/annealing/AnnealingPartitioner.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/annealing/AnnealingPartitioner.o casa/annealing/AnnealingPartitioner.d: ,g' > casa/annealing/AnnealingPartitioner.d
g++ -MM casa/algorithms/BinarySearch.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/algorithms/BinarySearch.o casa/algorithms/BinarySearch.d:  ,g' > casa/algorithms/BinarySearch.d
g++ -MM casa/Main.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS | sed 's,.*\.o:,casa/Main.o casa/Main.d:   ,g' > casa/Main.d
sed -e 's/://g' -e 's/[^ ][^ ]*\.d//g' -e 's/[^ ][^ ]*\.o//g' -e 's/[   \\][    \\]*/ /g' common/utility/PascalTriangle.d common/utility/Combinadic.d common/utility/CombinadicIterator.d minisat/solver/Solver.d casa/sat/SAT.d casa/io/Usage.d casa/io/SpecificationFile.d casa/io/ConstraintFile.d casa/io/OutputFile.d casa/covering/state/CoveringArray.d casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayEntry.d casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayRow.d casa/covering/state/CoveringArraySubRow.d casa/covering/space/CoveringArraySpace.d casa/covering/space/SingleChangeSpace.d casa/covering/space/GraftSpace.d casa/covering/bookkeeping/Options.d casa/annealing/Anneal.d casa/annealing/AnnealingSuccess.d casa/annealing/Bounds.d casa/annealing/AnnealingPartitioner.d casa/algorithms/BinarySearch.d casa/Main.d | tr ' ' "\n" | sort | uniq | tr "\n" ' ' | sed 's/^/ALL_INPUTS =/' > Dependencies
g++ -c -o common/utility/PascalTriangle.o common/utility/PascalTriangle.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o common/utility/Combinadic.o common/utility/Combinadic.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o common/utility/CombinadicIterator.o common/utility/CombinadicIterator.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o minisat/solver/Solver.o minisat/solver/Solver.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/sat/SAT.o casa/sat/SAT.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/io/Usage.o casa/io/Usage.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/io/SpecificationFile.o casa/io/SpecificationFile.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/io/ConstraintFile.o casa/io/ConstraintFile.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/io/OutputFile.o casa/io/OutputFile.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/covering/state/CoveringArray.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArray.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayEntry.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayEntry.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayRow.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayRow.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/covering/state/CoveringArraySubRow.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArraySubRow.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/covering/space/CoveringArraySpace.o casa/covering/space/CoveringArraySpace.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/covering/space/SingleChangeSpace.o casa/covering/space/SingleChangeSpace.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/covering/space/GraftSpace.o casa/covering/space/GraftSpace.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/covering/bookkeeping/Options.o casa/covering/bookkeeping/Options.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/annealing/Anneal.o casa/annealing/Anneal.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/annealing/AnnealingSuccess.o casa/annealing/AnnealingSuccess.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/annealing/Bounds.o casa/annealing/Bounds.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/annealing/AnnealingPartitioner.o casa/annealing/AnnealingPartitioner.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/algorithms/BinarySearch.o casa/algorithms/BinarySearch.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -c -o casa/Main.o casa/Main.C -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Werror -g -Icasa -Icommon -Icommon/utility -Iminisat/solver -Iminisat/include -DSEARCH_PROGRESS
g++ -o casa-1.1b common/utility/PascalTriangle.o common/utility/Combinadic.o common/utility/CombinadicIterator.o minisat/solver/Solver.o casa/sat/SAT.o casa/io/Usage.o casa/io/SpecificationFile.o casa/io/ConstraintFile.o casa/io/OutputFile.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArray.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayEntry.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayRow.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArraySubRow.o casa/covering/space/CoveringArraySpace.o casa/covering/space/SingleChangeSpace.o casa/covering/space/GraftSpace.o casa/covering/bookkeeping/Options.o casa/annealing/Anneal.o casa/annealing/AnnealingSuccess.o casa/annealing/Bounds.o casa/annealing/AnnealingPartitioner.o casa/algorithms/BinarySearch.o casa/Main.o 
etags casa/algorithms/BinarySearch.C casa/algorithms/BinarySearch.H casa/annealing/Anneal.C casa/annealing/Anneal.H casa/annealing/AnnealingFilter.H casa/annealing/AnnealingPartitioner.C casa/annealing/AnnealingPartitioner.H casa/annealing/AnnealingSuccess.C casa/annealing/AnnealingSuccess.H casa/annealing/Bounds.C casa/annealing/Bounds.H casa/covering/bookkeeping/Coverage.H casa/covering/bookkeeping/Options.C casa/covering/bookkeeping/Options.H casa/covering/cost/CoverageCost.H casa/covering/filter/CoveringArrayAnnealingFilter.H casa/covering/goal/CoverageGoal.H casa/covering/heuristic/CoveringArrayHeuristic.H casa/covering/report/IterationReport.H casa/covering/space/CoveringArraySpace.C casa/covering/space/CoveringArraySpace.H casa/covering/space/GraftSpace.C casa/covering/space/GraftSpace.H casa/covering/space/SingleChangeSpace.C casa/covering/space/SingleChangeSpace.H casa/covering/state/CoveringArray.C casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayEntry.C casa/covering/state/CoveringArray.H casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayRow.C casa/covering/state/CoveringArraySubRow.C casa/events/EventSource.H casa/events/Listener.H casa/io/ConstraintFile.C casa/io/ConstraintFile.H casa/io/OutputFile.C casa/io/OutputFile.H casa/io/SpecificationFile.C casa/io/SpecificationFile.H casa/io/Usage.C casa/io/Usage.H casa/Main.C casa/sat/SAT.C casa/sat/SAT.H casa/search/Filter.H casa/search/Goal.H casa/search/GreedyFilter.H casa/search/Guide.H casa/search/Heuristic.H casa/search/Node.H casa/search/SearchConfiguration.H casa/search/SearchFinish.H casa/search/Search.H casa/search/SearchIteration.H casa/search/StateGuide.H casa/search/StateSpace.H common/posix/getopt.h common/utility/Array.H common/utility/Combinadic.C common/utility/Combinadic.H common/utility/CombinadicIterator.C common/utility/CombinadicIterator.H common/utility/igreater.H common/utility/Lazy.H common/utility/PascalTriangle.C common/utility/PascalTriangle.H common/utility/pless.H common/utility/relation.H common/utility/SubstitutionArray.H minisat/include/Alg.h minisat/include/Heap.h minisat/include/Sort.h minisat/include/Vec.h minisat/solver/Solver.C minisat/solver/Solver.H minisat/solver/SolverTypes.H
root@pi314:/home/potato_head/GA/casa_1.1b#
```

Comment: The `make` command appears to have completed successfully - do you see an executable `casa-1.1b` file in the directory? That should be your program. Try running it. If there is no `install` target in the makefile then likely it is a standalone binary and you just need to copy it somewhere on your $PATH

Comment: Yes, You are right. I wasn't running the output binary. Instead I was trying to run the `make install` command. I don't understand why I didn't need that in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find any information about this software through a quick web search, so I don't know if the recommended installation method involves a configuration step before running `make`. If it does, `./configure` isn't the way, since there is no such file. Not all software built with `make` has a `configure` script.

Normally I'd recommend consulting the `README` (or similarly named) file, but it appears there might not be one.

There are three common ways software shipped with a makefile is built:

- Running `./configure` (and then after that, running other commands, usually `make`). But that doesn't appear to apply here. When there is such a script, usually it generates (or occasionally, customizes) `Makefile`.
- Manually editing `Makefile`. That might be the intended way for this software. `Makefile` does already exist.
- Just running `make`. That might be the intended way for this software. `Makefile` appears to be written in such a way that it will build the software even without being changed in any way first. To verify this, since I'm *not* an expert in makefile syntax and semantics, I saved its contents as `Makefile` in an empty directory and ran `make`. This attempted to run compilation commands (which of course failed because I didn't have the rest of the files), suggesting that your source code archive may ship with a ready-to-go makefile.

In short, **if you haven't tried just running `make` yet, try that.**

---

It appears that when you ran `make`, there were no errors and it created an executable called `g++ -o casa-1.1b`:

```
g++ -o casa-1.1b common/utility/PascalTriangle.o common/utility/Combinadic.o common/utility/CombinadicIterator.o minisat/solver/Solver.o casa/sat/SAT.o casa/io/Usage.o casa/io/SpecificationFile.o casa/io/ConstraintFile.o casa/io/OutputFile.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArray.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayEntry.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArrayRow.o casa/covering/state/CoveringArraySubRow.o casa/covering/space/CoveringArraySpace.o casa/covering/space/SingleChangeSpace.o casa/covering/space/GraftSpace.o casa/covering/bookkeeping/Options.o casa/annealing/Anneal.o casa/annealing/AnnealingSuccess.o casa/annealing/Bounds.o casa/annealing/AnnealingPartitioner.o casa/algorithms/BinarySearch.o casa/Main.o
```

That command links all the `.o` files (created by compiling the individual `.c` files in the source code archive) together into the program `casa-1.1b`.

It appears this file is just in the same directory where you ran `make`, since the `g++` command that produced it appears to specify paths relative to that folder. Running `./casa-1.1b` while in that directory may work to run the program.

If so, you can run it from there or manually copy the necessary files to install it. (That executable might be the only file you have to copy, or there may be others.)

Comment: I tried just running `make`. It runs and gives some output that I am not able to understand. But when I run `make install` afterwards it, it gives error `make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.`

And, Yes, there's no README or documentation on this.

Comment: @Potato_head check Eliah's updated answer, it may not have an install command with make.  Therefore you might just have to execute the program with the full path to the program instead of any kind of install